# Increment number in filename "Testing xx - Random.txt" in Batch script?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a  way to simply increment a number that's in a filename?

The filenames differ, but the number is always in the same place.

like this for example:

```
Chrome - Browsing 23 - Crash Report

Chrome - Browsing 24 - Navigation
```

So it should be easy to tell where the number is, as it's always in the exact same spot, only the text after it is changed.

I accidentally got the wrong number on Many files, made a duplicate of one number so all are back by 1, and it will take ages to remain them.

So is there a way to do this with a Batch Script?

Or perhaps something similar?

Thanks

Comment: It can be done fairly easily with the actual filename format.  Is it always `oneword hyphen oneword number morewords` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

:: This is just a listing for demonstration purposes
DIR "%sourcedir%\Chrome - Browsing *"

FOR /L %%a IN (102,-1,95) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=4*" %%g IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\Chrome - Browsing %%a*" '
  ) DO (
   SET /a newnum=1+%%a
   ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\Chrome - Browsing %%a*" "Chrome - Browsing !newnum! %%h"
  )
 )

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Here's a test-run result; first the `dir` listing, then the `rename`s generated:

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir

16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 95 - Crash Report
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 97 - Crash Report
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 99 - Crash Report
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 101 - Crash Report
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 96 - Navigation
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 98 - Navigation
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 100 - Navigation
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 102 - Navigation
               8 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   2,139,062,272 bytes free
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 102*" "Chrome - Browsing 103 - Navigation"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 101*" "Chrome - Browsing 102 - Crash Report"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 100*" "Chrome - Browsing 101 - Navigation"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 99*" "Chrome - Browsing 100 - Crash Report"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 98*" "Chrome - Browsing 99 - Navigation"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 97*" "Chrome - Browsing 98 - Crash Report"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 96*" "Chrome - Browsing 97 - Navigation"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 95*" "Chrome - Browsing 96 - Crash Report"
```

The trick is to execute the renames in **reverse** numerical order (`102` and `95` need to be changed to suit your range-to-be-renumbered, obviously). If the rename is attempted in normal order, you **may** have the circumstance

```
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 98 - Navigation
16/07/2014  14:25                 0 Chrome - Browsing 99 - Navigation
```

which would generate (with an **increasing** regime)

```
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 98*" "Chrome - Browsing 99 - Navigation"
REN "U:\sourcedir\Chrome - Browsing 99*" "Chrome - Browsing 100 - Navigation"
```

clearly, the first rename (98) would fail because the target name (99) already exists.

---

Edit : to adapt to general case of (words number morewords)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "pattern=word word - word word"

:: This is just a listing for demonstration purposes
DIR "%sourcedir%\%pattern%*"

:: De-luxe enhancement : automatically determine # of words in pattern (+1)
IF NOT "%pattern:~-1%"==" " SET "pattern=%pattern% "
SET /a words=1
SET "nwords=%pattern%"
:adwpl
SET /a words+=1
SET "nwords=%nwords:* =%"
IF DEFINED nwords GOTO adwpl

FOR /L %%a IN (102,-1,95) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=%words%*" %%g IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%pattern%%%a*" '
  ) DO (
   SET /a newnum=1+%%a
   ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%pattern%%%a*" "%pattern%!newnum! %%h"
  )
 )

GOTO :EOF
```

Now does most patterns...just set your pattern.

Comment: Can this be made to work with "Word Word - Word Word  xx"?
I noticed that it wasn't that easy to "adapt" the code for similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

Given two files

```
Chrome - Browsing 23 - Crash Report
Chrome - Browsing 24 - Navigation
```

and this script saved as test.bat

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off

for %%f in ("Chrome - Browsing*") do (
    set TEMP_FILENAME=%%f
    set TEMP_NUM=!TEMP_FILENAME:~17,4!
    set /A TEMP_NUM2=!TEMP_NUM!+1
    echo ren "!TEMP_FILENAME:~0,17!!TEMP_NUM!!TEMP_FILENAME:~21!" "!TEMP_FILENAME:~0,17! !TEMP_NUM2! !TEMP_FILENAME:~21!"
)
```

What you get out is the rename instructions:

```
ren "Chrome - Browsing 23 - Crash Report" "Chrome - Browsing 24 - Crash Report"
ren "Chrome - Browsing 24 - Navigation" "Chrome - Browsing 25 - Navigation"
```

If you change `echo ren` to `ren` it will actually run the commands. Take a backup first, it may break if the numbers hit three digits, or one digit, or the spacing is different, etc.

Comment: @Magoo has given a much more thorough answer - my answer here will not work because it will rename file 23 to be file 24, while file 24 still exists. They need to be renamed in descending order as Magoo suggests, or the rename command replaced with moving them into another (temporary) folder, with the new name.

Answer (score 0):

On my freebsd system, it comes to this. I'm assuming that it will work on debian linux as well.
It's a small script that will not just allow you to increment but add/substract any number in a filename by another number.

renumber.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
find * -name "*$1*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        filename=$(basename "$file")
        extension=${filename##*.}
        filename=${filename%.*}
        num=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/.*$2\([0-9]*\)$3.*/\1/")
        firstpart=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/\(.*$2\)$num.*/\1/")
        lastpart=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/.*$num\($3.*\)/\1/")
        addednum=$4
        changednum=$((num+addednum))
        echo "$num --> $changednum --> $firstpart$changednum$lastpart.$extension"
        mv -i "$filename.$extension" "$firstpart$changednum$lastpart.$extension"
done
```

The command syntax now is, for example

```
renumber.sh contAINS before after -20
```

Parameter 1 (here "contAINS") will limit the files to the ones containing this string. U can use an empty string "" here to get them all.

Parameter 2 (here "before") is the prefix or string right before the number. This may also be set to empty using ""

Parameter 3 (here "after") is the suffix, right after the number. Set empty using "".

Parameter 4 (here "-20") is the number to be added.

when I run this in a folder with the following files

```
EddycontAINS5678blablabefore120afterbla2345.txt
TomcontAINS1000_before121afterbla.txt
contAINS_12_before21after.txt
100before34aftercontAINS.app
```

It will change the files to

```
EddycontAINS5678blablabefore100afterbla2345.txt
TomcontAINS1000_before101afterbla.txt
contAINS_12_before1after.txt
100before14aftercontAINS.app
```